Apply style on different columns from different rules through a for loop
I try to highlight different columns from a DataFrame with different lists of words as references. If I chain the apply to the Styler object, it works, but if I apply successively the apply through a for loop, it highlights both columns with the last list of words.
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "bar", "corge"], "B": ["corge", "fred", "garply"]})

str_lists = [["foo", "bar"], ["corge", "fred"]]


def highlight_str(s, str_lst):
    return ["background-color: yellow" if v in str_lst else "" for v in s]

styled_df = df.style

# Works
styled_df.apply(lambda x: highlight_str(x, str_lists[0]), subset=["A"]).apply(
    lambda x: highlight_str(x, str_lists[1]), subset=["B"]
)

# Does not work
for str_lst, subset in zip(str_lists, df.columns):
    print(str_lst, subset)
    styled_df.apply(lambda x: highlight_str(x, str_lst), subset=[subset])

styled_df


why do you want to use a loop? Note that you could use a single apply call

@mozway I agree that your solution, which doesn't use the loop, is better. However, I still wonder why the solution resorting to successive .apply works, but not the one using a loop.

You don't have to chain style.apply not use a loop, just use a single call:
df.style.apply(lambda d: np.where(d.isin(dict(zip(d, str_lists))),
                                  'background-color: yellow', ''),
               axis=None)

Output:

Intermediate:
df.isin(dict(zip(df, str_lists)))

       A      B
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False


Didn't know about this axis=None option in Styler.apply. Great solutions!

style.apply doesn't apply the function on the style, but returns a new instance of style. So, in your code, you create a new style object and instantly discard it with each iteration. Reassign the style_df object, which is equivalent to chaining, makes it works:
for str_lst, subset in zip(str_lists, df.columns):
    print(str_lst, subset)
    style_df = styled_df.apply(lambda x: highlight_str(x, str_lst), subset=[subset])

Output:

Note: Without a loop, you can do:
styled_df = df.style.apply(lambda x: highlight_str(x, str_lists[df.columns.get_loc(x.name)]))

which gives a more accurate output:


Nice solution too, didn't think of using get_loc.
Besides, resigning the style_df object doesn't change the results, that actually was my initial try.
